# Add Ripple Effect to Prgramatically added View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml, ripple

I have a Image view which is added by program as :

```
imagen = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
```

Now I want to apply ripple effect to this.
I have library for ripple effect :

```
<com.skyfishjy.library.RippleBackground
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    app:rb_color="#0099CC"
    app:rb_radius="32dp"
    app:rb_rippleAmount="4"
    app:rb_duration="3000"
    app:rb_scale="6">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/centerImage"
        android:src="@drawable/demoImage"/>
</com.skyfishjy.library.RippleBackground>
```

In above code I have Image view in **XML** but my Image view create on run time so how can I apply ripple effect to run time `Imageview`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Add Ripple Effect to Prgramatically added View

You can inflate the view from xml and add it to the container layout programmatically.

```
View inflatedLayout= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_view, null, false);
        container.addView(inflatedLayout);
```

my_view.xml

```
<com.skyfishjy.library.RippleBackground
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    app:rb_color="#0099CC"
    app:rb_radius="32dp"
    app:rb_rippleAmount="4"
    app:rb_duration="3000"
    app:rb_scale="6">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/centerImage"
        android:src="@drawable/demoImage"/>
</com.skyfishjy.library.RippleBackground>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `ripple.xml` in `drawable` folder

ripple.xml :

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorFocusedHighlight">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

then

```
imagen.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ripple));
```

try this one instead to use third party for the ripple.